# foreach (where x => x.PROPERTY), how to set PROPERTY?

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, propertyinfo

I have an Object Student, I get one of the property's values by this method below

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propValue = typeof(Student).GetProperty(s);
```

Let's say that **s** (the string I passed into the GetProperty) was the property called "StudentName". I would then like to run a search based off that property, which was stored in propValue, such as:

```
foreach (Student stu in formStudents.Where(x => x.propValue == "John"))
```

However this does not work, as x.__ only fills in with properties of Student (even though valueProp contains a valid property of Student).

How can I override this so that is reads propValue as an actual value of student, or what other method will work for me?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the methods of `PropertyInfo`, to which you already have an instance of.  Look through the documentation if you can't guess what to used based on the method names.  You'll be able to find how to get that property's value from an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `propValue` is a `PropertyInfo` object, you need to use the [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
foreach (Student stu in formStudents.Where(x => ((string)propValue.GetValue(x, null)) == "John"))
```

However, from the description of problem, it seems like you might make your life easier by looking into the [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) library (also available on [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)):

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

...

foreach (Student stu in formStudents.Where("StudentName = @0", "John"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the `.GetValue(...)` method of the `PropertyInfo` object you got back from `.GetProperty(s)`:

```
foreach (Student stu in formStudents)
{
    var value = (string)propValue.GetValue(stu);
    if (value == "John")
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

You can rewrite to LINQ if you want to:

```
var matchingStudents =
    from stu in formStudents
    let propertyValue = (string)propValue.GetValue(stu)
    where propertyValue == "John";
    select stu;
foreach (var student in matchingStudents)
    ...
```